# Simple pointer troubles in C++ when removing an item from a buffer

Tags: c++, pointers, producer-consumer

I will say first of all that this is mostly due to my poor understanding of pointers.  I am encountering trouble in the following function:

```
//remove item function:

int remove_item(buffer_item * item) {
   buffer_item temp = buffer[position_to_consume_in_buffer];
   if (temp == NULL) {
      return -1;
   }
   else {
      *item = temp; //***How do I do this properly?
   }

   buffer[position_to_consume_in_buffer] = NULL;
   position_to_consume_in_buffer = (position_to_consume_in_buffer+1)%BUFFER_SIZE;
   return 0;
}
```

Definition of buffer_item:

```
/* buffer.h */
#ifndef BUFFER_H
#define BUFFER_H

typedef int buffer_item;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 7

#endif
```

And finally, where I am calling the function from:

```
//consumer thread:
void *consumer(void *param) {
    buffer_item * rand;
    unsigned int consumerseed = (unsigned int)pthread_self();
    while (1) {
    //sleep for a random period of time:    
    int consumersleeptime = rand_r(&consumerseed)%600+200;
    usleep(consumersleeptime);
    //wait on both semaphores
    sem_wait(&full);
    int check = pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
    if (check != 0) {
        printf("Check was not equal to zero for locking mutex in consumer. \n"); }
    //attempt to remove an item from buffer:
    int p = remove_item(rand);
    if (p == -1) {
        printf("Error encountered calling remove_item from consumer. \n"); 
    }
    int consumed = *rand;
    printf("Consumer consumed an item %d from the buffer. \n", consumed);
    //signal both semaphores
    check = pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
    if (check != 0) {
        printf("Check was not equal to zero for unlocking mutex in consumer. \n"); }
    sem_post(&empty);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here's what I want to do: I want to take the value of that indice from the buffer, and place it in a pointer.  This way, the variable item will contain the value of the indice in the buffer.  Then I set that indice that we consumed to NULL, so it is now empty.

I am having trouble storing the value of that indice in my pointer.  It causes a segmentation fault the way it is written right now.  I thought that saying *item = temp would set the value at the location pointed to by item to the value of temp.  However, I think instead it is setting it to the memory location of temp and thus I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: `NULL` should be used for pointers, not integers.

Comment: We can't tell what the type of `buffer` is or what `position_to_consume_in_buffer` is initially set to or how it is changed (presumably it's an integer). If you use a bad index, that will cause a segfault, and if `buffer` is not a double pointer, you're accessing it in a way that could possibly segfault as well.

Comment: Show how you're calling the function. Maybe you're not passing a valid pointer.

Comment: it doesn't seem you assign anything to rand after you declare it and before use it: how come you expect to remove something from it

Comment: @Giorgi Well, my thought process was that I was setting the value of rand, by setting *item = temp in my remove_item function.  I thought this would set the value of the place pointed to by item to be the value of temp, and thus rand would be the value of temp.  But clearly, I am wrong.

Comment: @Musicode: you can use it for start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-pJlnpkLp0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the pointer `rand`, but never initializing it. As a result, `remove_item` is trying to indirect through this unitialized pointer, which is undefined behavior,

You can just declare a normal variable, and pass its address to the `remove` function:

```
buffer_item consumed;
int p = remove_item(&consumed);
```

Comment: Let me give this method a shot.

Comment: I'm getting further with this method.  No more seg fault, and the values being placed into the buffer and removed from the buffer are equal.  It seems correct.